# Numpy dot return different values

Tags: python, numpy, normalize

Numpy dot returns different values after normalization. I have two functions which were supposed to return same values.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

def foo1(x, y):
    with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
        x_norm = np.nan_to_num(x / (np.linalg.norm(x, axis=0)))
    z = np.dot(x_norm, y / np.linalg.norm(y))
    print(z)

def foo2(x, y):
    x_norm = normalize(x, axis=0)
    z = np.dot(x_norm, normalize(y))
    print(z)
```

Minimal reproducible example

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])
y = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
foo1(x, y)
foo2(x, y)
```

Output

```
[[0.62190562]
 [1.47271032]]
[[1.0611399 ]
 [2.79304638]]
```

Expected first value.

Comment: Did you forget to pass `axis=0` to `normalize(y)`?

Comment: It dosen't make any sens in first function I also dont pass ```axis=0``` to y and function works, but after adding it to second one it gives expected value.

Comment: Taken from the numpy docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html If axis is None then either a vector norm (when x is 1-D) or a matrix norm (when x is 2-D) is returned.

Comment: `normalize` operates on `axis=1` by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your issue is arising from the fact that `y` is a 3x1 matrix. When you are calling [`normalize`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html), it is normalizing over the second axis (`axis=1`), where it normalizes each value individually. So

```
normalize(y) -> array([[1.], [1.], [1.]])
```

when instead you want

```
normalize(y, axis=0) -> array([[0.26726124], [0.53452248], [0.80178373]])
```

Making this change, both of your functions will return the same value `[[0.62190562]
 [1.47271032]]`